# asp textbox hangs at 4.1M characters. Need more cowbell

Tags: vb.net, paypal, .net-4.5

I need 10M characters to paste in a textbox. From what I have read, System.int32 is possible, but for some reason, my code will do 4Million characters, but hangs at 4.1M characters which is around 2^22.

By hang, I mean it doesn't get to Page_Load(), nor btnPressed_Click(). Instead it just does nothing. I don't know how to figure out what it is doing......

Code attached. Thanks for reading and any leads!

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes
Imports Class1
Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client


Partial Class _Default
Inherits MyPage
'Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad

    Beep()
End Sub



Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Me.PreRender

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

    validate_user()

End Sub


Public Class TempIsZeroException : Inherits ApplicationException
    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub
End Class



Protected Sub btnPressed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPressed.Click


    modalLoading.Hide()


End Sub



Protected Sub btnPressed_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPressed.PreRender

End Sub



End Class

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" validaterequest="false" %>
<%@ Register Src="header.ascx" TagName="header" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI"     TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <link href="<%=Application("styleurl")%>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Application("scripturl")%>"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
     .auto-style1 {
         width: 544px;
     }
     #txtAreaInfo {
         height: 116px;
     }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
   <uc1:header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
    <div id="MainDiv" runat="server">
  <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <script type="text/JavaScript">registerEndRequest();</script> 
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>
                  <table width="300px">
                      <tr>
                          <td style="width: 80px"></td>
                          <td class="auto-style1">
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtEntry4"     TextMode="multiline" runat="server" Width="240px" Height="141px" Style="margin-top: 0px" spellcheck="false" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td style="width: 80px"></td>
                          <td class="auto-style1">
                              <asp:Button ID="btnPressed" runat="server"     CssClass="purplebutton" Width="246px" Text="Drop, Create and Load Table" ToolTip="Creates table in EDW" Height="25px"    OnClientClick="javascript:showPopup('modalLoading');txtEntry5.value='';" />                          
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>

           </tr>
       </table>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:updatepanel>  
    </div>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="progress"     Style="display: none;">
        <div class="Progresscontainer">
            <div class="Progressheader">
                Loading, please wait...</div>
            <div class="Progressbody">
                <img id="loader" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
           <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalLoading" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlPopup"
        PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You may be running into the default max request length limits - maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3853767/2278086) will help?

Comment: That was it! Thanks Mark. You should remove your air of invisibility for a tip!

Answer (score 0):

Mark posted the solution in comment above. Thanks Mark!